# How to fix 404 error in wordpress admin-ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to custom submit **advanced custom fields pro** data which includes a image field using ajax without using the native submission acf provides.

It may seem like reinventing the wheel but this is the only way it works for my use case which is a **multi-step form**. Out of the box acf does not provide functionality for this.

I am currently getting **POST https://dev.energypages.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 ()** error and I am not sure why, I would much appreciate if a fresh set of eyes could look at my code and see if they can find any issues I can't.

Also I have been unsuccessful in getting the image data along with the string data.

**Javascript:**

```
$(".nexttwo").on('click', function() {
  resetErrors();

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
  var comid = getUrlParameter('cid');

  var companydata = new FormData(this);
  companydata.append("comdata", "company_info");
  companydata.append("cid", comid);

  $.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'post',
    data: companydata,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var status = data[i].code;
        var field = data[i].field;
        var message = data[i].msg;
        //var comid = data[i].cid;

        if (status == "200") {
          //successful validation
          if (animating) return false;
          animating = true;

          //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
          $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

          //show the next fieldset
          next_fs.show();
          //hide the current fieldset with style
          current_fs.animate({
            opacity: 0
          }, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
              //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
              //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
              scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
              //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
              left = (now * 50) + "%";
              //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
              opacity = 1 - now;
              current_fs.css({
                'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'
              });
              next_fs.css({
                'left': left,
                'opacity': opacity
              });
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function() {
              current_fs.hide();
              animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
          });
        } else {
          var msg = '<label class="acf-notice -error acf-error-message error" for="' + field + '">' + message + '</label>';
          $('input[name="' + field + '"], select[name="' + field + '"]').addClass('acf-error').before(msg);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
function company_info($post_id){
    if( isset($_POST['cid']) )
    $post_id = $_POST['cid'];

    // These files need to be included as dependencies when on the front end.
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');

    //Log form data
    $file_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
    $filename = $file_path.'companyinfo.txt';

    //Get form data
    $data = $_POST['comdata'];

    file_put_contents($filename, $data);

    $formdata = array();
    parse_str($data, $formdata);


    //Prepare company info
    $cname = strtolower($formdata['acf']['field_5bef0f8c743f6']);
    $clogo = $formdata['acf']['field_5bef0fac743f7'];
    $cwebsite = $formdata['acf']['field_5bef100b743f8'];
    $cphone = $formdata['acf']['field_5bef1032743f9'];
    $caddress = $formdata['acf']['field_5bef108a743fa'];

    $errorMSG = [];

    /* COMPANY NAME */
    if ( empty($cname) ) {
        $errorMSG[] = array('code' => 404, 'field' => 'acf[field_5bef0f8c743f6]', 'msg' => 'Company name is required');
    }

    /* COMPANY LOGO */
    if ( empty($clogo) ) {
        $errorMSG[] = array('code' => 404, 'field' => 'acf[field_5bef0fac743f7]', 'msg' => 'Company logo is required');
    }

    $success = [];

    if( empty($errorMSG) ){
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['acf[field_5bef0fac743f7]'];
        $upload_name = $_FILES['acf[field_5bef0fac743f7]']['name'];
        $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
        $filepath = $uploads['path']."/$upload_name";

        if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        }
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
        if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] )  ) {

            $file = $movefile['file'];
            $url = $movefile['url'];
            $type = $movefile['type'];

            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $type ,
                'post_title' => $upload_name,
                'post_content' => 'File '.$upload_name,
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
                );

            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, 0);
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

        }
        // Let WordPress handle the upload.
        //$img_id = media_handle_upload( 'acf[field_5bef0fac743f7]', 0 );

        file_put_contents($filename, $attach_id);

        update_field('field_5bef0fac743f7', $attach_id, $post_id);


        update_field('field_5bef0f8c743f6', $cname, $post_id);
        update_field('field_5bef100b743f8', $cwebsite, $post_id);
        update_field('field_5bef1032743f9', $cphone, $post_id);
        update_field('field_5bef108a743fa', $caddress, $post_id);

        $success[] = array('code' => 200);
        echo json_encode($success);

        exit();
    }

    echo json_encode($errorMSG);

    exit();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_company_info', 'company_info');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_company_info', 'company_info');
add_action('acf/save_post' , 'company_info', 20 );
```

**HTML OF IMAGE FIELD:**

```
<div class="acf-field acf-field-image acf-field-5bef0fac743f7" style="width:50%;" data-name="company_logo" data-type="image" data-key="field_5bef0fac743f7" data-required="1" data-width="50">
  <div class="acf-label">
    <label for="acf-field_5bef0fac743f7">COMPANY LOGO <span class="acf-required">*</span></label>
  </div>

  <div class="acf-input">
    <div class="acf-image-uploader" data-preview_size="thumbnail" data-library="all" data-mime_types="" data-uploader="basic">
      <input name="acf[field_5bef0fac743f7]" value="url=C%3A%5Cfakepath%5C4change-energy-logo.png" type="hidden">

      <div class="show-if-value image-wrap" style="max-width: 150px">
        <img data-name="image" src="" alt="" class="pk-pin-it-ready">
        <div class="acf-actions -hover">
          <a class="acf-icon -cancel dark" data-name="remove" href="#" title="Remove"></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="hide-if-value">
        <label class="acf-basic-uploader">
                    <input name="acf[field_5bef0fac743f7]" id="acf-field_5bef0fac743f7" type="file">                           </label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove processData: false, and check the url behind "ajaxurl" manualy. Making these 2 things must avoid getting a 404

Comment: I got this error (Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation) when i removed processData: false

Comment: Yes, because you're not saying anywhere that this is a json file. You need dataType: 'json' (and I keep saying that your url behind "ajaxurl" var is not correct

Comment: The issue was actually in my php function, thanks for your help.